# Geopandas color map not showing correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I have 3 used data:

1. df_prov = has province and count column
2. geojson
3. df_join = which have province, count and geometry(from geojson)

Heres's the data preview:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3EGn.png)

```
    0   Sumatera Utara  7430
    1   Jawa Barat  6192
    2   Jakarta Raya    4635
    3   Banten  2351
    4   Jawa Timur  1383
    5   Jawa Tengah 840
    6   Riau    782
    7   Sumatera Selatan    526
    8   Sumatera Barat  490
    9   Bali    459
    10  Lampung 379
    11  Aceh    377
    12  Kalimantan Timur    266
    13  Sulawesi Selatan    241
    14  Kepulauan Riau  230
    15  Yogyakarta  193
    16  Jambi   186
    17  Bengkulu    133
    18  Sulawesi Utara  109
    19  Bangka Belitung 98
    20  Kalimantan Barat    81
    21  Nusa Tenggara Timur 71
    22  Papua   55
    23  Sulawesi Tengah 54
    24  Kalimantan Utara    37
    25  Maluku  37
    26  Sulawesi Tenggara   33
    27  Kalimantan Tengah   31
    28  Kalimantan Selatan  30
    29  Nusa Tenggara Barat 21
    30  Sulawesi Barat  16
    31  Gorontalo   11
    32  Papua Barat 10
    33  Maluku Utara    8
```

this is a list of provinces and count, it shows that Sumatera Utara has the largest count of all.

but when I plot it, it shows that Kalimantan timur has the darkest value, not sumatera utara.

here's the code:
[plotting code[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sq6o.png)

```
    # set a variable that will call whatever column we want to visualise on the map
    values = 'Count'
    # set the value range for the choropleth
    vmin, vmax = 0,100
    # create figure and axes for Matplotlib
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(30, 10))
    # remove the axis
    ax.axis('off')
    # add a title
    title = 'Data Persebaran per Provinsi'
    ax.set_title(title, fontdict={'fontsize': '25', 'fontweight' : '3'})
    # create an annotation for the data source
    ax.annotate('Source: Laporan per Juni - November',xy=(0.1, .08),  xycoords='figure fraction', horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='top', fontsize=12 ,color='#555555')
    
    # norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1000) 
    # Create colorbar as a legend
    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='RdBu', norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
    # add the colorbar to the figure
    cbar = fig.colorbar(sm)
    # create map
    df_join.plot(column=values, cmap='RdBu', linewidth=0.8, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8', norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
```

heres's the map:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESg2H.png)

Could you please help me take a look and tell me what's wrong with the code?
thanks in advance!

Comment: When asking a question, please paste your code as text rather than linking an image - this makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @ChaddRobertson thanks! im a beginner. thanks for the tips! let me change it